# Reset input value after insertion on Meteor Collection

Tags: javascript, input, meteor

I want to clear my input value to "", after successful inserting on DB on Meteorjs i know i can do by .getElemenyById('id').value ="";, but its not working correctly, i have this code

```
    Template.agregado.events({
  'click #agregarMenu' : function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var nuevoMenu = document.getElementById('nuevoTipoDeMenu').value;
    Meteor.call('insertarNuevoMenu', {nuevoTipoMenu: nuevoMenu});

  }
```

Where #agregarMenu its a button like this

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="agregarMenu" type="submit">
```

and my input looks like this:

```
<input id="nuevoTipoDeMenu" class="form-control" placeholder="Agregar Tipo de Menu">
```

I just want to know where to put this code

```
 var resetMenu = document.getElementById('nuevoTipoDeMenu').value ="";
```

so after the value its inserted, the input value goes ""

Thanks reegards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass a callback to insert like this:

```
 Template.agregado.events({
  'click #agregarMenu' : function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var nuevoMenu = document.getElementById('nuevoTipoDeMenu').value;
    Meteor.call('insertarNuevoMenu', {nuevoTipoMenu: nuevoMenu}, function (error) {
      if (error) {
        // there was en error, item not inserted  
      } else {
        var resetMenu = document.getElementById('nuevoTipoDeMenu').value ="";
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: bro im trying to do the same with check box using jquery, but i have a problem now i want to uncheck te "check" value from a checkbox i have this code on the call back but its not working

$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', false).triggerHandler('click');

its just not working

Comment: Why the trigger handler?

Comment: sorry i copy paste that code, already working without that event handler $('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', false)